# Authorize & Authenticate access to static content (pdf)

Tags: asp.net, security

I have an **asp.net web app** and accessible with form authentication. Inside the folder structure looks like this:-

```
\myapp
\document\pdf\hello1.pdf
\document\pdf\hello2.pdf
\document\pdf\hello3.pdf
\document\pdf\hello4.pdf
```

http://localhost/myapp/document/pdf/hello1.pdf

Now these pdf files are used in the anchor links within the app. Now i want to enforce the authentication & authorization to restrict the direct access to these static resources. If there is access from outside the app, it should go to the login page.

I cannot change the path of the files in the anchor tags because i used it at many places across the app.

Is there a way to do with web.config ?

Pls suggest some solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: Has your Page with pdf links got anonymous access? If not so, then you may grant Read permissions on the PDF folder to the ASP.NET account (NT Services or so) and then on click of the link send the selected pdf file name/Id as input and deliver the content back as PDF file from the server.

Answer (score 1):

You should add to `web.config` the following lines to restrict access to 'document' folder only to authenticated users.
Unauthenticated users will be automatically redirected to login page, as desired.

```
<configuration>

..........
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name="TSAuthCookie" cookieless="UseCookies" 
    timeout="60" path="/"/>
 </authentication>
 <location path="document">
  <system.web>
   <authorization>
     <deny users="?"/>
   </authorization>
  </system.web>
 </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: sorry i just updated my question desc. The document folder itself contains another folder named pdf.

Comment: i tried to use like this <location path="document/pdf">. But it doesn't work.

Comment: what is actual behavior of your application? Files are 'public'?

Comment: the files are present inside the project under the folder. And right now it is public and i want to restrict its access from within the app only.

Comment: By default any file inside any folder of the project is protected.. Are you shure your files are public by now? If so post your Authentication configuration (or look at mine)

Answer (score 1):

For .NET 2.0/3.5/4.0 and IIS6 I found that the following was necessary to force static files such as .pdf in a specific folder to be processed by .NET:

1) IIS6 configuration:

A. In the properties for the website, go to the Home Directory tab and click Configuration
B. Double-click an existing "application extension" entry (such as .ascx) and copy the path found at "Executable" (this path will vary depending on the version of .NET in use; thus it's easier to copy & paste)

C. Cancel the dialog for Add/Edit Application Extension Mapping and click "Add" to add a new extension

D. Paste the path you copied in 1B into "Executable"

E. In "Extension" put .pdf (or other file extension)

F. choose "All verbs" or "Limit to" GET, etc. as needed; un-check "verify if file exists" if not a physical file on the server

G. Click OK on all dialogs

2) web.config configuration:

A. add the location for the restricted directory or file:

```
<location path="your_directory">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

B. Add the following to the httpHandlers section:

```
<add path="*.pdf" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" validate="true" />
```

Now .net will only serve .pdfs in your_directory to authenticated users (using forms authentication in my case).

Comment: How would you do this for IIS 7.5?  I tried adding .pdf as a Deny File Extension to the Request Filtering rules, and then added the restricted directory settings to the web.config file, and I'm still able to access and read the pdf file as an anonymous user.

Comment: there is no explaination where System.Web.StaticFileHandler is coming from

Answer (score 0):

You can use [location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx) element to have separate security settings for folders.

Or you can place a web.config file inside document folder and configure security in it.

Comment: only some files pass from the asp.net security, the rest like pdf did not pass.

Answer (score 0):

To enable web.config
 `<authorization>` elements to affect non ASP.NET file extensions you need to enable Wildcard Script Mapping on IIS6 (applies to IIS7 if classic pipeline mode is enabled), or use the integrated pipeline mode in IIS7.

Please see http://ruslany.net/2008/09/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-7-integrated-pipeline/

Then web.config entries such as the following will work:

```
 <location path="document">
  <system.web>
   <authorization>
     <deny users="?"/>
   </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Or you can simply add a mapping for the .PDF file extension to pass through aspnet_isapi.dll