# How to require login to view documents on a website?

Tags: html, vb.net, security, web

My website has a series of documents stored in a folder on the webserver (Windows 2012 R2).

The documents can be found on a page that can only be accessed by logged in users. These documents are PDF files that can be downloaded through the click of a hyperlink. They also can be viewed in the web browser.

Currently a user can copy the URL, give it to somebody else and they can use it to download the PDFs thereby not having to go through the login process to view the page behind the login page.

Let's say the URL is https://www.mywebsite.com/documents/adocument.pdf

How can I go about securing these documents so that the url can't just be sent around but prompts for a login instead?

Below is the code to get the documents. An These are then pushed into an ASP.NET placeholder.

```
Public Shared Function GetLoanDocLinks(ByVal iLoanID As Integer) As String
    Dim s As String

    s = ""
    Dim MyConn As FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection
    Dim Adaptor As FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim dr As DataRow
    Dim iNumRows, i As Integer
    Dim MySQL As String
    Dim myContext As HttpContext
    Dim MySession As HttpSessionState = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session

    myContext = HttpContext.Current

    ds = New DataSet

    'StrConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("FBConnectionString").ConnectionString
    MySQL = "SQL statement goes here"
    MyConn = New FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection(DBNAME.ConnStr)
    Adaptor = New FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDataAdapter(MySQL, MyConn)
    Adaptor.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@p1", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.Integer).Value = iID
    Try
        Adaptor.Fill(ds)
    Catch ex As Exception
        GenExternals.LogEntry("Error:" & ex.Message)
    End Try

    iNumRows = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count

    For i = 0 To iNumRows - 1
        dr = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)
        s = s & "<a href='documents/" & Trim(dr("Filename")) & "' target='+new'>" & Trim(dr("description")) & "</a>&#32;&#32;"
        s = s & "<br /> "
    Next
    s = s & "<br />"
    MyConn.Close()
    Adaptor = Nothing
    MyConn = Nothing

    GetLoanDocLinks = s
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authorize & Authenticate access to static content (pdf)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478203/authorize-authenticate-access-to-static-content-pdf)

Comment: An other option is to not link to the pdf directly but to have a .aspx page that will send the pdf data if the user is logged. This will allow you to add extra logic if you want (like statistics).